# 100% height for both floated div and non-floated div next to it

Tags: html, css

I would like to create 3 colored divs.

left: fixed width and 100% height

right: fills the remaining space (100% height and width (minus left div))

last div: inside the right div

This is what I have so far:

here is the CSS:

```
.left {
width:200px;
height:100%;
top:0;
position: absolute;
background: black;
float:left;
}

.right{
margin-left:210px;
background: green;
position: relative;
height: 100%;
}

.box {
width: 50%;
height: 200px;
position: relative;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background: black;
}
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fxWg7/1632/

This makes the div.right be the size of the box inside it, even though I tried to make it 100% of the window. How do I fix this?

Another question I have is: why can I not make the div.box have 100% height? If I try that, both div.right and div.box disappear.

Comment: Despite your question title, you _do not have_ a floated element here – see http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo, point 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 100% of the height of the window, add:

```
html, body
{
    height:100%
}
```

to you CSS. But if anything goes beyond the height of the window, it's a completely different problem.

Comment: I set it to 98.5% and that worked best with no overflow. So hacky. I'll have to learn more about this. Thanks

Comment: @aeroc, if you needed to do that, you probably want to add `padding: 0` and `margin: 0` so you can use `100%` (otherwise it will depend on the actual size of the window). Alternatively, you can use `box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box` (but you'll still need `margin: 0`).

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the concept of window with the concept of page.

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

are specifying that the `height` and the `width` of all the affected elements should fill their parent, not the whole window. You do not have content which would require size in your page, so your page's size is extremely small. This is why your `div`s disappear.

You need to set the size of the body with javascript.

Comment: Ok, I will learn about that. So far positioning divs has given me the most problems.

Comment: Do not panic, everybody has to accumulate the experience somehow.